# How do I get the triangular mesh of a tube in python?

Tags: python, mayavi

I'm looking to get the vertices and triangles of a 'tube' defined by a series of points in 3D space and a radius. I can render a tube like this using Mayavi:

```
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np
t = np.linspace(0, 20, 200)
mlab.plot3d(np.sin(t), np.cos(t), 0.1*t, t, tube_radius=0.1, tube_sides=20)
```

[image]

but how do I get a list of the surface vertices and triangles?
Any suggestions for other ways of achieving this in Python are also welcome!
Thanks in advance.